# Make screen shooter in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, linux-mint

I have to make script similar to `Screen Shooter`. Unfortunately I am green in this topic. In connection with this I would like to ask if it is possible to write such a script? I know `ScreenShots` are possible, but can they be handled?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example, screenshot script :

```
#!/bin/sh
import screen$RANDOM.jpg;
exit 0;
```

The script will display a cross-hair for selecting "screenshot size".

`import` is an imagemagick command : `sudo apt install imagemagick`
http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/imagemagick